# Findstr exporting data to text file

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I am trying to make a program that finds a name in a bunch of different text files, and then makes a list of the files it found that name in into another text file for a different program to pick up and run with.

I have a bunch of `findstr` lines for each of the files I'm looking for the name in, and the results need to be able to handle finding the name in multiple different files.

```
findstr /l /m /i /g:"imput.txt" "info\data\ListOfNames1.txt" >>"results.txt"
```

The list of names increases by 1 on every line.

I have `johnDoe` in the `imput.txt` and in `ListOfNames1.txt`, but `results.txt` is always blank.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your code looks good. Can you post short pieces of `input.txt` and `ListOfNamesx.txt` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was that `ListOfNamesX.txt` was in a bunch of folders and I forgot to mention the `%CD%` in the filepath. I guess that's what a good nights sleep can do for you.

Comment: I thought so, but it seemed so obvious, I didn't dare to ask... Please mark your answer as correct, so everybody knows the issue is solved.

Comment: Ummm...How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This works in the current directory:

```
findstr /L JohnDoe *.txt >> results.txt
```

But I guess you want the path in the results.txt file and you want to search different paths?

You can then pipe this to a program to use like this:

```
findstr /L JohnDoe *.txt | myprog.exe
```

For recursive search from current folder you can use:

```
findstr /S /C:"JohnDoe" *.txt >> results.txt
```

To specify a file of names you could use something like this:

```
findstr /S /G:"names.dat" *.txt >> results.txt
```

Your output might look something like this:

```
f1.txt:JohnDoe is a person
f2.txt:a person is JohnDoe 
onedown\f3.txt:also has JohnDoe in
```